# Error number -128 Applescript

Tags: applescript

I have a simple applescript that opens Safari, opens a web page 100 times (long story) and then waits 300 seconds to close Safari.

Here is the code:

```
set theURL to "https://sites.google.com"



tell application "Safari"

    activate

    repeat 100 times

        try

            tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab --with properties {URL:theURL}

            set URL of document 1 to theURL

        on error

            open location theURL



        end try

    end repeat


end tell

delay 300

tell application "Safari"
    quit
end tell
```

The first part of the script runs famously.  When I get past the delay, I am getting an error:

error "Safari got an error: User canceled." number -128

I tried to just run it without opening multiple web pages  Just activate Safari, wait 10 second and quit.  I get the same problem.

Has anyone dealt with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not getting the error you describe. However I am seeing a bug where Safari is not activating if the application was not already running when I run the code.

This code seems to work as you'd expect...

```
set theURL to "https://sites.google.com"

tell application "Safari" to activate

tell application "Safari"
    activate

    repeat 2 times
        try
            tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab
            set URL of document 1 to theURL
        on error
            open location theURL
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

delay 5

tell application "Safari"
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: I am running it when Safari is not running.  Where I think I am getting the problem is that all the pages are not open when I try to close.  I am going to have to rethink the process and perhaps open a page, close it and repeat that function.